# Robocopy File Transfer Backup using SQL Server

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I have a job running robocopy to copy files from the SQL server to a backup drive.

The job runs a CmdExec type job to call a batch file that runs robocopy. my issue is although the files copy over fine the error reports dont get registared I tested this by changing the source file to a bogus drive. It still reports job success. I have narrowed it down to it only sees robocopy and when it runs the tool is reports sucess. e.g. if i only type "robocopy" in to the batch file it still reports success.

Here is the code I am running to try and result in an error when a legite error has occorred:

robocopy "C:\backup\" "D:\backup" 
SET /A errlev="%ERRORLEVEL & 24%"
EXIT /B %errlev%

Any thoughts?

Comment: This question probably shouldn't be tagged sql.  Just so happens that you are copying files involved with sql server.

Comment: 1) script out the job, post it to your question 2) post the batch file that runs Robocopy.  3) Don't make changes to them other than to remove servernames / company info.  4) Before you do all of this, make sure that you've *fully* read the SQLTEAM post I showed you in my answer and implemented it he instructs.  If it's still not working, I'll do my best to replicate the problem on my end.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at: [ss64's page on robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Also, first time that I've seen this: [RoboCopy GuI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx).  Bet it might help you produce a working as expected command line.

Oh, an maybe I'm wrong about sql being an important part of this question.  See here for a really neat guide over at [SqlTeam.com](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/robv/archive/2010/02/17/61106.aspx) that looks like it EXACTLY answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

In your job step, check to make sure that you've selected "Quit the job reporting failure" in the "On failure action". Also, under "Process exit code of a successful command" make sure that you have 0. There are some other successful "error codes", as Maassql mentions, but I'd start with 0 until you get things working as expected, then add in the additional codes which you want to count as non-errors.

This is assuming SQL 2008. If you're on a different version, the prompts may be different.

Comment: Bothh have been set as stated but still not getting any results.

Comment: I did run your command line here and the job errored out as expected. If I think of something else, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but

your code seems to work, but must be wrapped in a batch file, then the sql needs to call the batch file instead of robocopy directly

found the answer here

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/robv/archive/2010/02/17/61106.aspx